# Current user to string

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I faced a problem with showing data. Before I used current users UID as a key but now I'm using the custom key and I don't know how to call this key as a string in my code.

My code this part ( child(user.getUid() )

[image]

```
FirebaseUser userUID;
userUID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        final DatabaseReference NameRef = database.getReference().child("No server").child(userUID.getUid()).child("name");
        final DatabaseReference LastNameRef = database.getReference().child("No server").child(userUID.getUid()).child("lastName");
        final DatabaseReference EmailRef = database.getReference().child("No server").child(userUID.getUid()).child("email");
```

What changed

[image]

I want make user a string "dan ned".

Edit:

```
 FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        final DatabaseReference NameRef = database.getReference().child("No server").child(user.getUid()).child("name");
        final DatabaseReference LastNameRef = database.getReference().child("No server").child(user.getUid()).child("lastName");
        final DatabaseReference EmailRef = database.getReference().child("No server").child(user.getUid()).child("email");

      NameRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                  final String strName = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                  textName.setText(strName);
              }
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

          }
      });

        LastNameRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    final String strLastName = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    textLastName.setText(strLastName);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        EmailRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    final String strEmail = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    textEmail.setText(strEmail);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The last screenshot is what you want to achieve? "dan ned" is the name of the user that comes from FirebaseUser object?

Comment: Last screenshot is what i have now. dan ned comes from register page i just combine name and lastname. Now i want to show data on my page and for that i have to do child("dan ned") or make user == "dan ned". Thats what i think.

Comment: So you don't know how to read the data under "dan ned"?

Comment: I know how to read data under "dan ned" thats more like i dont know how to read "dan ned". I will edit my question to show my full code.

Comment: I dont know how to read data under "dan ned " now whan i changed UID to "dan ned" before i just called UID of current user but now i cant do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to attach three listeners in order to read those three values. You can use only one, as you can see in the following lines of code:

```
String name = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference nameRef = db.child("No server").child(name);
nameRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            String key = snapshot.getKey();
            Log.d("TAG", key); //It will print "dan ned"
            String email = snapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", email); //It will print "DanilNed@gmail.com"
            String lastName = snapshot.child("lastName").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", lastName); //It will print "Ned"
            String name = snapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", name); //It will print "Dan"
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I am getting error     "java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()" how can i fix it?

Comment: Most likely your user is not authenticated, case in which you can use  `DatabaseReference nameRef = db.child("No server").child("dan ned");`, as the name should always be a part of the reference.

Comment: But what if i am gonna use another user? I can't use child("dan ned"). Should i create new question?

Comment: In that case, you should use the name of the corresponding user. Let's say I'm a part of your app, then you should call `.child("Alex Mamo")`. If you have a hard time implementing this functionality, please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Yes i understand how it works but i can't change it all the time by my hand so i need a string that will take key name or name and last name. We have something like that in here "String name = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();" but here i get an error from the first comment. Sorry if you cant understand what i am trying to say my english is pretty bad.

Comment: There is no need to apologize. I understand what you say. If you have another specific situation, please post a new question here, so we can take a look at it.